# "Taken out to the medowlands" what does this mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, idiomatic-language

Watching an interview with Anthony Bourdain and he says the following,

Interviewer: "Have you ever fired anyone?"

Anthony: "... I'd go to the hiring person (female) and say, 'Pauly', I don't wanna see him no more, he needs a little **ride out in the metal lands...**" What does this mean? I googled it but nothing close came up as a result.

The link is below. Fast forward to 17:40.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vUEFdWAKpf0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a joking allusion to Sonny Corleone's order, in *The Godfather*, to have his father's driver **Paulie** executed for betraying Don Vito to a rival family:

> SONNY: *to Clemenza, after Paulie exits* I want you to take care of that sonofabitch right away. Paulie sold out the old man, that stronz'. **I don't want to see him again.** Make that first thing on your list, understand?

The next day Clemenza has Paulie drive him and an associate on a series of errands around New York City. At night, as they are driving through the **Meadowlands** on the New Jersey side of the Hudson River, Clemenza has Paulie pull over onto the shoulder so he can take a leak; when Clemenza leaves the car the associate shoots Paulie.